# Adding Multiple Values to a Post Meta Key

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, post-meta, terms

I have a question about adding multiple post meta values to a post meta key.

Here is a [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) to the WordPress `add_post_meta();` function in question.

The `$unique` parameter is a little on the fuzzy side of clarity for me.

> Whether or not you want the key to be unique. When set to true, this
>   will ensure that there is not already a custom field attached to the
>   post with $meta_key as its key, and, if such a field already exists,
>   the key will not be added.

If this is set to true, will I be able to add multiple values to a single post meta key?

I am looking to create ONE unique post meta key per post. This key is set as a hidden key. (Prefixed with an underscore - Example: `$meta_key = '_task-name';`)

Is it possible to add multiple post meta values to this single unique post meta key, in array format?

So when I fetch this post meta key from the post using `get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key);` one post might have 3 or 4 tasks names assigned to it.

Would I be better off just using Taxonomies and Terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might have had the same question...

`add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);`

The `$unique` parameter means that there must not already be an existing post meta key for the key / value you are about to add to the post object as post meta.

You can store a single value or an array as post meta. There is no limitation for the type of data stored.

`get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);`

When you fetch the post meta from your post object using `get_post_meta();` the `$single` parameter means you either want to fetch one result as a string, or fetch the entire array of data stored in that particular post meta key.

In my opinion, if you plan on storing multiple pieces of data for a post object, you're better off using taxonomies and terms. If you're only storing a quick small array, it's a simpler solution to just store your data as an array as post meta for your post object.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert an associative array into the post_meta_field.

Here is a quick little function to grab the data afterward (did not test):

```
function grab_task_name_array($post_id) {
    $new_array = array();
    $array = get_post_meta($post_id,'_task-name'); //do not put true as third parameter (this would return string and not array)
    foreach($array[0] as $key => $value)
     $new_array[$key] = $value;

    return $new_array;
}
```

If you wanted to store a multidimensional array, some more checks would be needed.